# How can I effectively use a switch case to only show certain movies to children who are of age to purchase them?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

We are creating an application that allows customers to buy movie tickets. I am having issues with utilizing the age verification to then create a case switch that takes the Rating and shows them movies they would only be allowed to purchase.

For the ratings, we used an ENUM.

```
// an enum for all the ratings that a movie can have
public enum Rating 
{
    G,
    PG,
    PG13,
    R,
    NC17
}
```

And we are reading the movies from a file utilizing the following code:

```
List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>(); //Creating a new list for movies
string input; //String to store input from user
string Filepath = @"C:\\Users\\jackpirtle\\source\\repos\\HW4PirtleCinema\\movie (1).txt"; //Creating string of filepath to read the movie.txt from my file explorer
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Filepath); //Creates a new streamreader that connects to the filepath we just created
// Begin creating the list of movies and the main program to gather user input. 
do
{
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nHere are a list of the movies showing at Starlight Cinema.\nEnter a corresponding number to select a movie.\n"); //Displays the listing of movies

        if (File.Exists(Filepath)) //Only runs if the FilPath exists
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream) //Keeps Running untdil its the end of the file
            {
                string movieName = sr.ReadLine();
                Rating rating;
                switch (sr.ReadLine())   //Switch case statement to determine the ratings, and spit out the ratings from the enum that we created earlier
                {
                    case "G":
                        rating = Rating.G;
                        break;
                    case "PG":
                        rating = Rating.PG;
                        break;
                    case "PG-13":
                        rating = Rating.PG13;
                        break;
                    case "R":
                        rating = Rating.R;
                        break;
                    case "NC-17":
                        rating = Rating.NC17;
                        break;
                    default:
                        rating = Rating.G;
                        break;
                }
                int screen = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());  //Initializes variable screen as integer and coverts it to in as the streamReader
                double price = Convert.ToDouble(sr.ReadLine()); //Initializes variabl eprice as double and converts it to double as streamReader
                List<string> movieTimes = new List<string>(); //Creates a new list of movieTImes
                movieTimes.Add(sr.ReadLine()); //Adds whatever is on the file to this list line by line
                movieTimes.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                movieTimes.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                Movie movie = new Movie(movieName, rating, screen, price, movieTimes); //Calling movies given the Name, rating, screen, price and times
                movies.Add(movie); //Adding the movies to Movie
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < movies.Count; i++) //Creating a for loop to display the movies onto the console
            {
                Console.WriteLine("" + i + "" + "." + movies[i].movie + " |Rating: " + movies[i].rating.ToString() + " |Price: $" + movies[i].price + "|\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n------------------- Order Movie Tickets -------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe file of movies can't be found."); //If the file doesn't exist, display an error message
        }

        userInput = ValidEntry(1, movies.Count);  //Calls valid entry function 
        bool movieConfirmed = ConfirmSelection(movies[userInput].movie + " - " + movies[userInput].rating);  //Initializes movieconfirmed as boolean to coorelate to the ConfirmSelection method
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("\n------------------- Order Movie Tickets -------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("\nYou have selected " + movies[userInput].movie + ". Please select a time below to view your selection!"); //Displays a message to user sayign what movie they selected, and asing what time they want to watch

    } while (!confirm);  //Code continues until it is !confirm
```

If there is a simple way to use a switch case to hide rated R movies from children under the age of 13, and so forth, then I would greatly appreciate any help. Been working on this for a while and have been stuck. Any feedback is welcome!

I tried to use a case switch and also a simple if else statement but am not sure how to hide certain elements of the file utilizing the ENUM variables.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the forum. Could you post up a sample of the data from the file that you're reading? An example with two films would be useful.

Comment: I am not sure because you didn't share data yet. But I think you don't need enum here. You can just clarify your object, and load all file to that list. Then you can easily use LINQ to filter whatever you want.

Comment: Movies
G
0
0.0
null
null
null
Free Guy
PG-13
1
9.99
3:00pm
5:30pm
8:00pm
Jungle Cruise
PG-13
2
9.99
3:15pm
5:45pm
8:15pm
The Night House
R
3
10.99
3:30pm
6:00pm
8:30pm
Paw Patrol
G
4
9.49
3:45pm
6:15pm
8:45pm
Respect
PG-13
5
9.99
4:00pm
6:30pm
9:00pm
The Suicide Squad
R
6
8.99
4:15pm
6:45pm
9:15pm

Comment: Above is the data. This comes from a text file where it is one line per entry (Line 1: Movie Title. Line 2: Rating. Line 3: Index. Line 4: Price. Lines 5-7: Times.

Comment: So we are simply trying to prevent underage children from being able to view certain movies from the list. So we want a certain selection of that data to be viewable based off of the age that is provided to us. The logic is simple: G everyone can purchase, PG everyone can purchase, PG13 only those above 13 can purchase, R above 13 can purchase, and NC 17 only 17 and older can purchase.

Comment: @JackPirtle Do you have time to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
Rating rating = sr.ReadLine() switch
{
    "PG" => Rating.PG,
    "PG-13" => Rating.PG13,
    "R" => Rating.R,
    "NC-17" => Rating.NC17,
    _ => Rating.G,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First find a suitable place for the user to enter the age

```
Console.Write("Please enter your age：");
int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Then modify the level:

```
switch (sr.ReadLine())   //Switch case statement to determine the ratings, and spit out the ratings from the enum that we created earlier
{
    case "G":
        rating = Rating.G;
        break;
    case "PG":
        rating = Rating.PG;
        break;
    case "PG-13":
        if (age > 13)
        {
            rating = Rating.PG13;
        }
        else {
            rating = Rating.G;
        }
        break;
    case "R":
        if (age > 13)
        {
            rating = Rating.R;
        }
        else {
            rating = Rating.G;
        }
        break;
    case "NC-17":
        if (age > 17)
        {
            rating = Rating.NC17;
        }
        else {
            rating = Rating.G;
        }
        break;
    default:
        rating = Rating.G;
        break;
}
```

Another method: Divide users into three grades according to the entered age, and the three grades correspond to three ranges；

```
Console.Write("Please enter your age：");
int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string Flag = "";
if (age < 13 && age > 0)
{
    Flag = "A";
}
else if (age >= 17)
{
    Flag = "B";
}
else if (age >= 13 && age < 17)
{
    Flag = "C";
}
else
{
    Flag = "error";
}
switch (Flag)
{
    case "A":
        //G PG
        break;
    case "B":
        //G PG PG13 R NC17
        break;
    case "C":
        //G PG PG13 R 
        break;
    default:
        //
        break;
}
```